# Web scraping on multiple pages using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the reviews for a product using the below url in R. When I run the below code, I am able to get a single review scraped.

```
comment<- read_html("https://www.influenster.com/reviews/chobani-greek-yogurt")
comment %>% html_node(".content-item-text") %>% html_text()
comment %>% html_node(".date") %>% html_text()
```

However, when I use the below code for scraping multiple comments on multiple pages, it returns NULL.

```
reviews <- lapply(paste0('https://www.influenster.com/reviews/chobani-greek-yogurt?review_page=2', 2:50),
                function(url){
                    url %>% read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes(".content-item-text review-text") %>% 
                    html_nodes(".date") %>% 
                    html_text()
                  })
```

Comment: In your first code, you search for `".content-item-text"` by itself. In the nested query, you are searching for `".content-item-text review-text"`, which is not found (even in the first code).

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code achieve what you are looking for?

```
comment<- read_html("https://www.influenster.com/reviews/chobani-greek-yogurt")

reviews <- c()
dates <- c()

for(i in 1:10){
  reviews <-  c(reviews,
                comment %>%
                html_node(paste0(".review-item:nth-child(", i, ") .review-text")) %>%
                html_text())
  dates <- c(dates,
             comment %>%
             html_node(paste0(".review-item:nth-child(", i, ") .date")) %>%
             html_text())
}

for(j in 2:50){
  comment <- read_html(paste0("https://www.influenster.com/reviews/chobani-greek-yogurt?review_page=", j))
  for(i in 1:10){
    reviews <-  c(reviews,
                  comment %>%
                  html_node(paste0(".review-item:nth-child(", i, ") .review-text")) %>%
                  html_text())
    dates <- c(dates,
               comment %>%
               html_node(paste0(".review-item:nth-child(", i, ") .date")) %>%
               html_text())
  }
}
```

Just note that I am in the UK and the extracted dates seem to be corrected (- 6 hours what is stated on the site)

Furthermore, apologies for the multiple looping I am not yet very quick at translating loops to the apply functions :)

Comment: @ Immanuvel Vasanth You are welcome. Please accept my answer and consider an up vote if you found it helpful :)

Comment: @ Frost_Maggot Looks like my upvote is accepted but publicly wont be visible as i am new to the platform..